# what is the difference between llm and llm chain in langchain?

Tags: python, streamlit, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

this is llm:

```
question=st.text_input("your question")
llm=OpenAI(temperature=0.9)
if prompt:
    response=llm(prompt)
    st.write(response)
```

then if we need to execute a prompt we have to crate llm chain:

```
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain

question=st.text_input("your question")
llm=OpenAI(temperature=0.9)

template="Write me something about {topic}"
topic_template=PromptTemplate(input_variables=['topic'],template=template)

topic_chain=LLMChain(llm=llm,prompt=topic_template)

if prompt:
    response=topic_chain.run(question)
    st.write(response)
```

I am confused because we used `llm(prompt)` in the first example, but we created `LLMChain(llm=llm,prompt=topic_template)` in the second example. Could you please explain the difference between these two approaches and when it's appropriate to use one over the other?

Answer (score 4):

Direct LLM Interface:

```
    llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.9)    
    if prompt:            
        response = llm(prompt)
        st.write(response)
```

In this approach, you're directly using an instance of the OpenAI class. This class likely has an implementation of the model that can directly process a given prompt and return a response. The process is straightforward: you provide a prompt, the model generates a response.

LLMChain Interface:

```
   from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate.  
   from langchain.chains import LLMChain

   template = "Write me something about {topic}".  
   topic_template = PromptTemplate(input_variables=['topic'], 
   template=template)

   topic_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=topic_template)

   if prompt:    
     response = topic_chain.run(question).  
     st.write(response)
```

This approach involves a higher level of abstraction using the LLMChain and PromptTemplate classes. Here's a breakdown of what each part does:

PromptTemplate: Defines a structured prompt where you can specify variables that get filled in, ensuring that prompts adhere to a specific format.

LLMChain: Seems to be a chain or sequence of processes that likely utilize the underlying LLM. It takes a structured prompt and the underlying model to generate a response.

When to use which?

Direct LLM Interface: This is suitable for more flexible or ad-hoc tasks where the prompt structure can vary widely and doesn't need to adhere to a predefined format.

LLMChain Interface: This is apt for more structured tasks where consistency in the prompt format is essential. By using a chain, you can also potentially extend functionalities, like adding pre-processing or post-processing steps before and after querying the model.

Answer (score 3):

In simple terms

LLM is the base class for interacting with language models like GPT-3, BLOOM, etc. Handles lower-level tasks like tokenizing prompts, calling the API, handling retries, etc.

```
   from langchain import OpenAI

   llm = OpenAI() 
   llm("Hello world!")
```

LLMChain is a chain that wraps an LLM to add additional functionality.
**HANDLES PROMPT FORMATTING**, input/output parsing, conversations, etc.
Used extensively by higher level LangChain tools.

```
    from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain

    template = "Hello {name}!"
    llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=PromptTemplate(template))

    llm_chain(name="Bot :)")
```

So in summary:

LLM -> Lower level client for accessing a language model
LLMChain -> Higher level chain that builds on LLM with additional logic

Answer (score 2):

I was confused about llm chain (I know that chain creates complex pipeline) because it was always used with the `prompt template`. it turns out chain requires two components:

1- Prompt template

2- language model

[From here](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains/foundational/llm_chain)

> An LLMChain consists of a PromptTemplate and a language model (either
> an LLM or chat model). It formats the prompt template using the input
> key values provided (and also memory key values, if available), passes
> the formatted string to LLM and returns the LLM output.

If you think about it, when you create a chain combining 2 tools, you have to pass the output of the first tool to the second tool as input and that is why we are using `prompt templating`

Answer (score 0):

In the examples, `llm` is used for direct, simple interactions with a language model, where you send a prompt and receive a response directly.

On the other hand, `LLMChain` in `langchain` is used for more complex, structured interactions, allowing you to chain prompts and responses using a `PromptTemplate`, and is especially useful when you need to maintain context or sequence between different prompts and responses.